# Dimensions of a custom view consisting of a shape drawable 

Tags: android, layout, custom-controls, drawable

I am pretty much following the sample found in: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#shape-drawable

```
  public class CustomDrawableView extends View {

  private ShapeDrawable mDrawable;

  public CustomDrawableView(Context context, AttributeSet attr) {
  super(context, attr);

  int x = 10;
  int y = 10;
  int width = 300;
  int height = 50;

  mDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());
  mDrawable.getPaint().setColor(0xff74AC23);
  mDrawable.setBounds(x, y, x + width, y + height);
  }

  protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
  mDrawable.draw(canvas);
  }
  }

  // XML snippet where I am using this custom view
  <com.example.shapedrawable.CustomDrawableView
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

I am actually using this in a ListView, so it gets inflated in my Adapter's getView method (I know this works because it looks fine for non-custom views).

I noticed that unless I specify a "dp" value for layout_width and layout_height, then it will not draw. However if I use something arbitrary like 500dp for layout_width and layout_height, then it appears!
I am very confused - why isn't it using the height/width dimensions I specify in code when I use wrap_content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I had to override onMeasure and return the measurements of my drawable. I used the LabelView APIDemo as an example.